snaplogic java script expression for the router snap
'I couldn't figure out the java script expression on router snap in snaplogic, I would like to route the input document to two different output view based on the if condition:
here is my requirement, I'm having a list of dictionaries and I want to check if the name filed contains .csv file name for first two dictionary objects, if either one of first two objects contains .csv files then all good and route it to  output-1,
if both the objects doesn't contain .csv then I would need to send it to output-2
this is the expression I was trying, but not working ($.keys()[0] != 'Name') && ($.keys()[1] != 'Name')
here is how the data looks like:
NOTE: first dictionary doesn't contain any files, so name filed will be taking the directory name.'
[
  {
    "original": {
      "Name": "test/",
      "Type": "Directory",
      "Size (in bytes)": 0,
      "Path": "s3:///data/directory/test/",
      "Owner": "aws-data-root",
      "Update date": "2024-04-11T00:35:02.000Z",
      "Creation date": "unknown",
      "Permissions": "unknown",
      "original": {
        "Date": "2024/03/25",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "test",
        "DateToday": "2024/03/24",
        "flag": "1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "test.csv",
    "Type": "File",
    "Size (in bytes)": "492",
    "Path": "s3:///data/test/2024/03/25/test.csv",
    "Owner": "aws-devdata1-root",
    "Update date": "2024-03-25T00:18:25.000Z",
    "Creation date": "unknown",
    "Permissions": "unknown",
    "original": {
      "Name": "test/",
      "Type": "Directory",
      "Size (in bytes)": 0,
      "Path": "s3:///data/directory/test/",
      "Owner": "aws-data-root",
      "Update date": "2024-04-11T00:35:02.000Z",
      "Creation date": "unknown",
      "Permissions": "unknown",
      "original": {
        "Date": "2024/03/25",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "TEST",
        "DateToday": "2024/03/24",
        "flag": "1"
      }
    }
  }
]


'This is the expression I tried, but it's not giving the expected result
($.keys()[0] != 'Name') && ($.keys()[1] != 'Name')
this is what I've tried but no luck'

try this for the first router condition:
jsonPath($, "[0].original.Name").indexOf('.csv') != -1 ||
jsonPath($, "[1].Name") != -1
Second router condition:
jsonPath($, "[0].original.Name").indexOf('.csv') == -1 && jsonPath($, "[1].Name") == -1
